# Multiple Google charts not displaying properly on the same page

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've got 4 charts displayed on a single page. When drawn individually they work perfectly fine, but when I try to have more than 1 they're not all displayed. I have also noticed that when resizing the window (hence refreshing the charts), the "active" chart can change.

Here's my method that draws the charts:

```
function drawChart() {
    // Occurrences per step
    var data_occ =  new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data_occ.addColumn('string', 'Step');
    data_occ.addColumn('number', 'Number');
    data_occ.addRows([
        ['NO_STOP_DEP', 2057],
        ['FIND_STOPS_DEP', 795],
        ['FIND_STOPS_ARR', 423],
        ['FIND_ROUTES', 416],
        ['FIND_PATHS_0', 416],
        ['NO_STOP_ARR', 371],
        ['FIND_PATHS_1', 359],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_FAILED', 274],
        ['FIND_PATHS_2', 274],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t1d', 185],
        ['OK', 147],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t1d', 145],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t1a', 138],
        ['NO_PATH', 129],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_FAILED', 118],
        ['NO_JOURNEY', 118],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_cs1', 117],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t2d', 115],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT_t1d', 111],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t1a', 79],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_cs1', 75],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t2d', 73],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t2a', 66],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_cs2', 66],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t3d', 66],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION', 65],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT', 56],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT_FAILED', 54],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION', 26],
        ['NO_ROUTE_ARR', 4],
        ['NO_ROUTE_DEP', 3]
    ]);
    var opt_occ = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Occurrences of each step'
        }
    };
    var chart_occ = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_occ'));
    chart_occ.draw(data_occ, opt_occ);

    // Sum of durations per step
    var data_dur =  new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data_dur.addColumn('string', 'Step');
    data_dur.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    data_dur.addRows([
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t2d', 4271651.423530579],
        ['NO_STOP_DEP', 954578.8992916346],
        ['FIND_STOPS_DEP', 711477.470664978],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT_t1d', 604728.3424301147],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t2d', 483084.8451423645],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t1d', 399811.6393585205],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t3d', 391471.8716468811],
        ['FIND_PATHS_1', 173883.78058815002],
        ['FIND_STOPS_ARR', 164751.4531224966],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t1d', 158291.4034690857],
        ['FIND_PATHS_2', 154918.55130004883],
        ['FIND_ROUTES', 125470.71777877212],
        ['NO_STOP_ARR', 82222.14379951358],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_cs1', 45374.44926452637],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t1a', 29688.884063720703],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_cs2', 21626.706924438477],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_cs1', 13983.793979644775],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t2a', 13081.894062042236],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION', 11718.449104309082],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_FAILED', 9777.992935180664],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_FAILED', 9182.082992315292],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT', 8991.909969329834],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t1a', 8132.20499420166],
        ['NO_ROUTE_ARR', 5709.329235076904],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT_FAILED', 5620.268951416016],
        ['FIND_PATHS_0', 4501.938883662224],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION', 3359.796012878418],
        ['NO_PATH', 1778.0850104540586],
        ['OK', 1419.4850099533796],
        ['NO_JOURNEY', 1267.5709964483976],
        ['NO_ROUTE_DEP', 334.49600982666016]
    ]);
    var opt_dur = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Cumulative duration of each step (ms)'
        }
    };
    var chart_dur = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_dur'));
    chart_dur.draw(data_dur, opt_dur);

    // Average of durations per step
    var data_dur_avg =  new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data_dur_avg.addColumn('string', 'Step');
    data_dur_avg.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    data_dur_avg.addRows([
        ['NO_ROUTE_DEP', 111.49866994222005],
        ['NO_ROUTE_ARR', 1427.332308769226],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT', 160.5698208808899],
        ['NO_PATH', 13.783604732202004],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_cs1', 387.8158056797125],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t2d', 4200.737783846648],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION', 180.2838323739859],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t1a', 102.93930372407165],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_cs1', 186.45058639526368],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t2d', 58515.77292507642],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t2a', 198.21051609154904],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_cs2', 327.6773776430072],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t3d', 5931.3919946497135],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION', 129.22292357224686],
        ['OK', 9.656360611927752],
        ['NO_STOP_ARR', 221.623029109201],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t1a', 215.13684104145437],
        ['NO_STOP_DEP', 464.06363601926813],
        ['FIND_STOPS_DEP', 894.9402146729284],
        ['FIND_STOPS_ARR', 389.483340715122],
        ['FIND_ROUTES', 301.6123023528176],
        ['FIND_PATHS_0', 10.821968470341885],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT_t1d', 5448.003084955989],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_DIRECT_FAILED', 104.07905465585215],
        ['FIND_PATHS_1', 484.35593478593324],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_t1d', 2161.1439965325435],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_1CONNECTION_FAILED', 33.51125179677114],
        ['FIND_PATHS_2', 565.3961726279155],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_t1d', 1091.6648515109357],
        ['JOURNEY_GET_2CONNECTION_FAILED', 82.86434690831071],
        ['NO_JOURNEY', 10.742127088545743]
    ]);
    var opt_dur_avg = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Average duration of each step (ms)'
        }
    };
    var chart_dur_avg = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_dur_avg'));
    chart_dur_avg.draw(data_dur_avg, opt_dur_avg);

    // Average duration comparison today vs yesterday
    var data_dur_avg_cmp =  new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data_dur_avg_cmp.addColumn('string', 'Step');
    data_dur_avg_cmp.addColumn('number', 'Yesterday');
    data_dur_avg_cmp.addColumn('number', 'Today');
    data_dur_avg_cmp.addRows([
    ]);
    var opt_dur_avg_cmp = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Average duration of each step (ms)'
        }
    };
    var chart_dur_avg_cmp = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_dur_avg_cmp'));
    chart_dur_avg_cmp.draw(data_dur_avg_cmp, opt_dur_avg_cmp);
}
```

I have also uploaded the code to [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epfo523h/) so that you can see for yourself. You can play with the integer at the top, to select which graphs will be displayed. Having a value that is not a power of 2 (that is, display more than one graph) will cause the following:

- the div will be sized, I mean the layout indicates that it is present
- nothing will be drawn in the div

Here's an example with 2 graphs drawn, one is properly drawn and the second one is blank:

[image: example with one graph not working]

We can clearly see that the *Average duration* div has a size, but is blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [the known issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2066) that was reported in [google-visualization-issues](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues) repository:

> The problems people have seen with the sizing of multiple instances of
>   material charts should be resolved with this new release. You can
>   change your code to load "1.1" now so that when the candidate release
>   becomes available, you will be using it.

There are at least two solutions available at the moment.

**Option 1. Using the frozen version loader.**

Since the *rollout of the v43 candidate release that would fix this problem*
switch to using the frozen version loader.

Steps:

1)Add a reference to loader: `<script src="http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

2)Then load a `43` version of library: `google.charts.load("43", { packages: ["corechart", "gauge", "table", "timeline", "bar"] });`

3)Replace `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` with `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

[**Modified jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/epfo523h/1/)

**Option 2. Render charts synchronously**

Since a `draw` function is *asynchronous*, we utilize `ready` event handler to draw charts sequentially, in that case multiple chart should be rendered properly as demonstrated below.

```
function drawChart(chartsQueue,index) {
    index = index || 0;
    if (index === chartsQueue.length)
        return;



    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(chartsQueue[index].id));
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
        drawChart(chartsQueue, index + 1); //draw next chart
    });
    chart.draw(chartsQueue[index].data, chartsQueue[index].options);
}
```

[**Modified jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/epfo523h/2/)

Comment: I already saw your same answer on another question, but I figured this was not applicable for me as I don't use the _material_ charts. Was I migrated automatically to material, hence making me vulnerable to this bug? If so, that's a bad move from Google.

Comment: I just checked, I'm using `google.charts.Bar` which is the (soon to be) legacy chart, not the material one. Is the bug applicable to these charts too? I wouldn't think so.

Comment: I think this issue concerns every **material** charts including Material Bar Chart (`google.charts.Bar` class from  `bar` package). But regarding legacy "Classic" Bar Charts ( `google.visualization.ColumnChart` or  `google.visualization.ColumnChart` from `corechart` package), indeed, it not an issue - [proof concept](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/epfo523h/3/)

Comment: I was loading the API through `google.com/jsapi`, which migrated me to Material Charts. I wasn't aware of that, so I thought I didn't have Material Charts. I've migrated to `gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` and changed the init code (loading the v43 frozen of Oct/2015). Now everything is working again. Thanks!